# Django- Get Foreign Key Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

How can I Get A Foreign Key Model Type?

For Example:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I Want To Get category Model In SubCategory.

How Can I Do It?

Comment: What do u mean? do u wanna get the class type?

Comment: I Exactly Want To Get Class Type Without Any Instance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
subcategory = SubCategory.objects.get(pk=given_pk)
subcategory.category
```

EDIT:

```
subcategory._meta.get_field('category').rel.to
```

Comment: Oh... Then is very simple: always Category.

Comment: Kidding Me? It's A Sample. I Want The To Get The Foreign Key Dynamically!

Comment: How to do `category = Category.objects.get(pk=given_pk)` `category.subcategory `? I wanna do it this way, but it's not working.

Answer (score 31):

**For Django>=2.0**

```
>>> SubCategory._meta.get_field('category').remote_field.model
>>> 'my_app.models.Category'
```

To get the model name use the `__name__` class property.

```
>>> SubCategory._meta.get_field('category').remote_field.model.__name__ 
>>> 'Category'
```

Answer (score 13):

ForeignKeys are `ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor` objects. So that's what you are really working with. You'll get that if you run `type(SubCategory.category)`. From here you can use two ways to get the actual Class/Model referred to.

```
SubCategory.category.field.rel.to  # <class 'path.to.Model'>
SubCategory.category.field.rel.to.__name__  # 'Category'

# or these will do the same thing

SubCategory._meta.get_field('category').rel.to
SubCategory._meta.get_field('category').rel.to.__name__
```

If you don't know the attribute name until run-time, then use `getattr(SubCategory, attributeNameVariable)` to get your `ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor` object for that ForeignKey field.

Answer (score 8):

also for django > = 2.0

```
>>> SubCategory._meta.get_field('category').related_model
>>> <class 'my_app.models.Category'>
>>> SubCategory._meta.get_field('category').related_model._meta.model_name
>>> 'category'
```