# Is there a way to get type of related field from a model queryset in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Can I get type of related field from a model queryset?

Let consider example model:

```
class Semester(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Active")

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Name")
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, verbose_name="Semester")
```

if I have some field name in variable and queryset I can do this:

```
querySet = Subject.objects.all()

some_field_name = 'name'
field_type = querySet.model._meta.get_field(some_field_name).get_internal_type()
```

Is there any way to get related field type, for example:

```
querySet = Subject.objects.all()

some_field_name = 'semester__active'
field_type = ?
```

Comment: `for subject in querySet: print type(subject.semester.active)`?

Comment: thansk for your suggestion, but type() return type of an object, unfortunately I need field type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for any help!

I find solution with some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627745/django-get-foreign-key-model):

```
main, related = some_field_name.split("__")
field_type = querySet.model._meta.get_field(main).rel.to._meta.get_field(related).get_internal_type()
```

Comment: This works but is ugly as it re-implements part of Django :-s

Answer (score 2):

Try using `get_field_by_name`:

```
field_type = querySet.model._meta.get_field_by_name(some_field_name).get_internal_type()
```

From [Django's source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/options.py):

```
def get_field_by_name(self, name):
    """
    Returns the (field_object, model, direct, m2m), where field_object is
    the Field instance for the given name, model is the model containing
    this field (None for local fields), direct is True if the field exists
    on this model, and m2m is True for many-to-many relations. When
    'direct' is False, 'field_object' is the corresponding RelatedObject
    for this field (since the field doesn't have an instance associated
    with it).

    Uses a cache internally, so after the first access, this is very fast.
    """
```

Also try:

```
field = querySet.model._meta.get_field_by_name("semester")
field_type = field[0].rel.to._meta.get_field_by_name("active").get_internal_type()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately .get_field_by_name("active") return FieldDoesNotExist error. Your another suggestion querySet.model._meta.get_field_by_name("semester").rel.get_field_by_name("active").get_internal_type() return AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rel'

Comment: Please try again the second suggestion with `field_type = field[0].rel.get_field_by_name("active").get_internal_type()`

Comment: unluckily your edited suggestion return AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'get_field_by_name'

Comment: Hmmm ok. What about `field[0].rel.to.get_field_by_name("active").get_internal_type()` ?

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Semester' has no attribute 'get_field_by_name'. You should add _meta, as you can see in my ansewer: field[0].rel.to._meta.get_field_by_name('active').get_internal_type(). Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Glad you found your answer. Cheers