# Get referenced Model by field name on Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have the following model on Django:

```
class Statue(models.Model):
 id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=128L)
 ref_id = models.ForeignKey('Foo', db=column='ref_id')

class Foo(models.Model):
 id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=128L)
```

Now I have statue object `statue_a = Statue()` and `field = 'ref_id'` 
and I'm trying to find `Foo` (the related class) by field (the field name), how do I do that ?

Comment: So what's wrong with `statue_a.href_id`? Also try to name your classes with valid python names(even Foo or Bar), in order to get specific examples.

Comment: `raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist`

Comment: why would you need that ? What is the usecase?

Comment: `Statue` could have many reference fields, `ref_id` could reference `Foo` or `Bar` etc. , I'm trying to find out which class is being referenced by `ref_id`, so I can write a new `Foo` or `Bar` object accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django- Get Foreign Key Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627745/django-get-foreign-key-model)

Comment: possible, but topic name is fairly different (I've searched for the answer and couldn't find anything)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
statue_a = Statue()
statue_a._meta.get_field('ref_id').rel.to
```

Comment: Exactly! I was beginning to think what I'm doing is so far-off it might just be poorly designed.