# Django get the name of related model doesn't recognize `rel` attribute

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a dictionary with some attributes of model fields, so I followed the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627745/django-get-foreign-key-model) to get the name of the model referenced by `ForeignKey` fields, but I get an error `AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'rel'`.

This is my code:

```
def get_fields(model, fields):
    fields_meta = []

    for field in fields:
        field_meta = {}

        field_meta['name'] = field
        field_meta['title'] = force_text(model._meta.get_field(field).verbose_name)
        field_meta['type'] = model._meta.get_field(field).get_internal_type()
        if field_meta['type'] == 'ForeignKey':
            field_meta['rel_model'] = model._meta.get_field(field).rel.to
        field_meta['null'] = model._meta.get_field(field).null
        field_meta['max_legth'] = model._meta.get_field(field).max_length

        fields_meta.append(field_meta)

    return fields_meta
```

I can't find what I am missing.

Comment: can you show your model ?

Comment: It is actually a dynamic function that works with whatever model you send as a parameter

Comment: try to use `model._meta.get_field(field).remote_field.to` maybe it will help https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24317

Comment: The `ForeignObjectRel` doesn't have a `rel` property to access the model you should use the `field.remote_field.model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [get_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) directly to retrieve the field instances of the model and this will simplify your code.

```
def get_fields_meta(model, field_names):
    fields_meta = []

    for field in model._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True):
        if f.name not in field_names:
            continue

        field_meta = {}

        field_meta['name'] = field.name
        field_meta['title'] = force_text(field.verbose_name)
        field_meta['type'] = field.get_internal_type()
        if field_meta['type'] == 'ForeignKey':
            field_meta['rel_model'] = field.remote_field.model
        field_meta['null'] = field.null
        field_meta['max_legth'] = field.max_length

        fields_meta.append(field_meta)

    return fields_meta
```